# Subsetting rows from a Pandas dataframe with a datetime index does not work

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, indexing, subset

I have this data:

[image]

[image]

For a reproducible example:

```
sp500.head(21).to_json()
'{"Close":{"1580428800000":3225.52,"1580342400000":3283.66,"1580256000000":3273.4,"1580169600000":3276.24,"1580083200000":3243.63,"1579824000000":3295.47,"1579737600000":3325.54,"1579651200000":3321.75,"1579564800000":3320.79,"1579219200000":3329.62,"1579132800000":3316.81,"1579046400000":3289.29,"1578960000000":3283.15,"1578873600000":3288.13,"1578614400000":3265.35,"1578528000000":3274.7,"1578441600000":3253.05,"1578355200000":3237.18,"1578268800000":3246.28,"1578009600000":3234.85,"1577923200000":3257.85}}'
```

My Pandas version is `'1.0.0rc0'`

What is going wrong here and what I should do?

Comment: For me working correctly, what is your pandas version?

Comment: Please see updated post

Comment: hmmm, so maybe problem is bug, tested in pandas 0.23.1